# Idiomatic go way to compare 2 slices to see which element has been removed

Tags: go

I am using [RethinkDB](https://www.rethinkdb.com/) in my application and I have a lobby that has users.

RethinkDB has the ability to watch for changes to a table and when changes happen it automagically emits the changes so you can do whatever you want with the data, right now I'm trying to make it so when a user leaves the lobby I can send a websocket out to remove the user. The only thing is I'm trying to find out where the difference is in the before / after data which is a slice of `members`, this is the data:

```
type change struct {
    NewVal *fields `gorethink:"new_val,omitempty"`
    OldVal *fields `gorethink:"old_val,omitempty"`
}

type fields struct {
    ID      string `gorethink:"id"`
    Owner   string `gorethink:"owner"`
    Inqueue bool   `gorethink:"inqueue"`
    Members []struct {
        SteamID  string `gorethink:"steamid"`
        Username string `gorethink:"username"`
    } `gorethink:"members"`
    Messages []struct {
        Username  string    `gorethink:"username"`
        Message   string    `gorethink:"message"`
        CreatedAt time.Time `gorethink:"createdAt"`
    } `gorethink:"messages"`
}
```

Right now I'm doing

```
func (l *lobby) watchChanges() {
    db := common.DB()
    query := gorethink.Table("Lobbys").Get(l.ID).Changes()
    res, err := query.Run(db)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    go func(res *gorethink.Cursor, l *lobby) {
        defer res.Close()
        changes := new(change)
        for res.Next(&changes) {
            if changes.NewVal != nil && changes.OldVal != nil {
                switch {
                case len(changes.NewVal.Members) > len(changes.OldVal.Members):
                    // Member has joined so announce who it was.

                case len(changes.NewVal.Members) < len(changes.OldVal.Members):
                    // Member has left so announce who it was.
           -------->
                case len(changes.NewVal.Messages) > len(changes.OldVal.Messages):
                    // New Message was recieved so announce the message.

                }
            }
        }
    }(res, l)

    select {
    case <-l.KillMe:
        res.Close()
        break
    }
}
```

The new entries are easy enough I'll just take the end off the slice and send that, but when it comes to the user leaving, how can I compare the `changes.NewVal.Members` and `changes.OldVal.Members` to see which index was removed so I can send the right member to remove through the websocket. Hope my question is clear let me know if it isn't.

**This is how I'm currently doing it**

```
removedIndex := 0
for i, oldMember := range changes.OldVal.Members {
    foundMissing := true
    for _, newMember := range changes.NewVal.Members {
        if reflect.DeepEqual(oldMember, newMember) {
            foundMissing = false
        }
    }
    if foundMissing {
        removedIndex = i
        break
    }
}
```

but it feels a bit hacky, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the old and new members by a unique and sortable key. It looks like SteamID might be suitable for this purpose.  Iterate through both slices checking for added and deleted elements by comparing the keys.

```
func diff(old []*member, new []*member) {
  sort.Sort(bySteamID(old))
  sort.Sort(bySteamID(new))
  i, j := 0, 0
  for i < len(old) && j < len(new) {
    switch {
    case old[i].SteamID < new[j].SteamID:
        fmt.Println(" delete", old[i].SteamID)
        i++
    case old[i].SteamID > new[j].SteamID:
        fmt.Println(" add", new[j].SteamID)
        j++
    default:
        i++
        j++
    }
  }
  for i < len(old) {
    fmt.Println(" delete", old[i].SteamID)
    i++
  }
  for j < len(new) {
    fmt.Println(" add", new[j].SteamID)
    j++
  }
}
```

<kbd>[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/sVeHTPCsl_)</kbd>

Comment: Is this more efficient than using the way I've posted in the bottom of my question?

Comment: @Datsik `reflect.DeepEqual` is quite expensive, so I would imagine so!

Comment: It is more efficient in many scenarios and correctly handles scenarios not covered by the code in the question.

Comment: Building two maps (by SteamID) and comparing them might be more efficient if lists of members are large.